# Can ffmpeg wait until new input?

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg for video streaming, but I have images and images convert to video then streaming. I want encoder wait the image but ffmpeg starts and makes all image then close.

Comment: Share your full command and log.

Comment: dcraw -a -c -q 0 -6 *.nef | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -probesize 10000M -vcodec ppm -re -r 1 -i - -vcodec mpeg4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 1 -f mpeg4 udp://127.0.0.1:1234

Comment: At what speed is dcraw piping images?

Comment: When encoder started fps was 2.2 then it dropped to 0.2,0.2 fps is constant